# Adjust UIButton font size to width

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following code:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 25, 25);

[[button layer] setCornerRadius:5.0f];
[[button layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
[[button layer] setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[button.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 25, 25)];

[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[topics objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] unread]] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The issue is that when the string in the text is not long, it shows fine (1-2 digit). However, when it's quite long (3++ digit), all I can see is a red button, with no text inside. How do I adjust this?

I don't think that:

```
[button.titleLabel setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES];
```

does the job, right?

Comment: It should work, or theLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES.

Comment: It works by `titleButton.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)`

Answer (score 328, accepted):

Try this:

```
button.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping //<-- MAGIC LINE
```

I'm not sure why this does the trick but it does :)

Comment: thanks, whereas button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeClip; <-- MAGIC LINE is depreciated now

Comment: @yunas Replace UILineBreakModeClip with NSLineBreakByClipping

Comment: Nvm, that just made it change `numberOfLines` to 0

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all (MAGIC LINE) but totally works. Thanks Apple.

Answer (score 37):

```
button.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

should do the work on its own **if you are using Auto-Layout** and have set a constraint on the button's width.

The other options (minimum scale factor, number of lines etc) can still be used to customize further according to your needs, but are not required.

Answer (score 19):

The answer from EliBud doesn't work on iOS 8. 
I found a solution which works on iOS 8.
Below is a swift code:

```
let label = self.button?.titleLabel
label?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.01
label?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(100)
```

You can play with label?.lineBreakMode as I found that results varies for different break modes.

Comment: .adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true - how can I do the same with a NSTextField and a resizable window?

Comment: That looks to me it as the same as using Xcode IB selecting label and seting it to Autoshrink minimum font scale to 0.01

Comment: there is no AutoShrink option when using NSTextField

Comment: UITextField has an option to auto shrink text, whereas NSTextField doesn't. So I think you need manually adjust font to fit text field width.

Answer (score 13):

### Swift 4 extension

```
extension UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var adjustFontSizeToWidth: Bool {
        get {
            return self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
        }
        set {
            self.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
            self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = newValue;
            self.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping;
            self.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters 
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: what do u use tag for?

Comment: For be available to make the getter

Comment: Can you describe more deeply what do you mean, please?

Comment: I use tag like a flag to define if the adjusting enabled.

Comment: why dont u just use self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth ? what for do u need extra thing?

Answer (score 10):

in latest swift this seems to work for me

```
button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1
button.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByClipping
```

Answer (score 10):

iOS 10.3 solution based on the other answers here:

```
    button.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 1
    button.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    button.titleLabel!.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
```

---

Nobody mentioned `baselineAdjustment` yet; I needed it because the button label becomes vertically misaligned after `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` takes effect. Apple's `baselineAdjustment` documentation:

> If the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property is set to `true`, this
>   property controls the behavior of the text baselines in situations
>   where adjustment of the font size is required. The default value of
>   this property is `alignBaselines`. This property is effective only when
>   the `numberOfLines` property is set to `1`.

---

FWIW, I could never get the label perfectly aligned.

Answer (score 9):

`adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` wasn't working for me until I set a width constraint on my button in Interface Builder.

Setting the constraint kept the button from growing in size and therefore not realizing it had to shrink the text.

Answer (score 4):

based on Nik Kov's answer:

```
import UIKit


    extension UIButton {
        @IBInspectable var adjustFontSizeToWidth: Bool {
            get {
                return titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
            }
            set {
                titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = newValue
                titleLabel!.lineBreakMode             = .byClipping
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This works, but the font size is getting decreased a lot, like from 17 to 12. Is there any way to increase the titlelabel's width when the string is bigger ?

Comment: @R.Mohan sure, but this all about fixed width. Just make constraints not fixed, and it will grow. Don't set both leading/trailing, or make one of them >=

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 13.1 with Swift 5, I had to provide `contentEdgeInsets` also to adjust the paddings.

```
extension UIButton {
    @IBInspectable var adjustFontSizeToWidth: Bool {
        get {
            return self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth ?? false
        }
        set {
            self.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
            self.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = newValue;
            self.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping;
            self.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
            self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

if none of the other answers helps, make sure you set the default storyboard style value and then `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` should work.

[image: buttons props]

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30238173)

Comment: Super helpful. My titleLabel wasn't adjusting to fit, it was because the style was set to 'Plain' and not 'Default'. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Xamarin.iOS solution

```
var accountButton = new UIButton();
accountButton.SetTitle("Account", UIControlState.Normal);            
accountButton.TitleLabel.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
accountButton.TitleLabel.Lines = 1;
accountButton.TitleLabel.LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.Clip;
accountButton.TitleLabel.Font = accountButton.TitleLabel.Font.WithSize(35);
```

I ended up setting the font size to ensure the font was "large" before the system adjusts the size to fit.

Answer (score 1):

I was working with tvos and somehow none of the above mentioned solutions were working for me. So I had do it using Configuration

```
    var buttonConfig = mButton.configuration! as UIButton.Configuration
    buttonConfig.title = "Remove from Favorites"
    buttonConfig.contentInsets = NSDirectionalEdgeInsets(top: 8, leading: 8, bottom: 8, trailing: 8)
    buttonConfig.titleLineBreakMode = .byClipping   //This line here does the trick
    mButton.configuration = buttonConfig

    mButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
    mButton.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
    mButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    mButton.setNeedsLayout()
```

Now You may not need all of these going forward based on your case but i still wrote them just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Below solution worked for me:

```
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

The developer documentation explains this property as:

> A Boolean value indicating whether the object automatically updates
>   its font when the device's content size category changes.