# custom font on UIbutton title clipped on top of word

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have uploaded a custom font and applied this font on the title of a UIbutton using the following code

```
videoButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"LaurenScript" size:20];
```

The problem is that the title is being clipped on the top of the first letter (see photo below). I tried the same font on the UIlabel and it works fine so it is not a problem with the font. I tried also to change the rectFrame using

```
[videoButton.titleLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 600)];
```

but that didn't do anything.
Has anybody a clue of how I can fix this problem?
Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I had a similar problem, where a diaeresis got cut off on top of the titlelabel.
I made a UIButton subclass and used this code to fix the problem:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect frame = self.titleLabel.frame;
    frame.size.height = self.bounds.size.height;
    frame.origin.y = self.titleEdgeInsets.top;
    self.titleLabel.frame = frame;
}
```

Comment: This should be best answer.

Comment: I have the same issue with UITabBarItems clipping custom fonts. layoutSubviews isn't available to subclass on UITabBarItems, anyone know a fix for that?

Comment: If you are still facing issues with text clipping with custom fonts please check my answer - can be applied to `UITabBarItem`'s also

Answer (score 34):

Select button in Interface builder and check for set a vertical alignment panel in the control section Below is example:

[image]

Comment: Best answer I have seem for this problem so far!

Comment: This seems to be the equivalent of labelName.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill which also works

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is still an issue for anyone, but I found that (with using a custom font) the above solutions did not ultimately fix the issue, especially for a custom `UIButton` created solely programmatically.

Here is how I managed to fix this issue, with 1 line in particular that resolved the clipping issue:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

[button setTitle:@"Nice!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:<CUSTOM FONT NAME> size:buttonWidth/3.0f]];
button = CGRectMake(0, 0, <WIDTH>, <HEIGHT>);
```

Here was the line that resolved the clipping:

```
[button setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentFill];
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else who still were stuck. Happy coding!

Comment: You saved me an hour! Thank you

Comment: Worked perfect for me!  This should be accepted as the best answer!

Answer (score 5):

had same problem using a button with an image and text with a custom font.
Everything had to be align centered vertically. And image not stretched.
this worked out fine for me.

```
btn.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
btn.contentMode = .center
btn.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 4):

I try this in swift 2.1, I adapt this code from [Antoine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485701/antoine) answer. This may not good code but it solve my problem for now. You should make it better for you self.

```
import UIKit

class CustomUIButton: UIButton {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if var titleFrame : CGRect = titleLabel?.frame{

            titleFrame.size = self.bounds.size
            titleFrame.origin = CGPointZero
            self.titleLabel!.frame = titleFrame
            self.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .Center
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is this (sad) solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10200908/352628

I have a similar problem. It seems that the titleLabel is just very uncontrollable, and to get control you need to inject a UILabel subview to the button... That makes me sad :(

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing :(

Answer (score 0):

[image]In my case the button title label was aligned vertically, but text needed insets on top.

self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5.0, left: 0.0, bottom: 0.0, right: 0.0)