# iOS cutting off UILabel/UIButton with some fonts

Tags: ios, swift

I have custom fonts in my project. But i detected some of the fonts that comes also with XCode have the same problem. For unknown reason the if i set accents to a capital letter (which is very common in Spain, like **Á**lgreba) the top of the text is cutting of.

[image]

For other fonts is more clear since i can't even see half accent. I can do a trick which is with UILabel setting a height constraint, but this trick doesn't apply to UIButton or to the title of the navigationBar.
I tried also in UILabel calling sizeToFiT with no succeed.

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225761/custom-font-on-uibutton-title-clipped-on-top-of-word    Also, if this does not work, you can add label behind custom button, so that label acts like button title and then add height constraint to label. Not so elegant solution, but it should work.

Comment: `button.layer.masksToBounds = false`?

Answer (score 8):

i had same problem using a button with an image and custom font.
this worked out

```
btn.contentVerticalAlignment = .fill
btn.contentMode = .center
btn.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Answer (score 1):

I used `.center`, but now it's `.fill` that resolves this problem for me. Using the interface builder press the following button:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had to add a separate label with constraints aligned to this button, and put a space as the button's title. I think, the button couldn't handle the font size change properly, so my case is specific, but it might help if the other answers won't fix it.

Don't forget to fix the height of the button!