# UIButton was cut when use Helvetica Neue LT Std font

Tags: ios, fonts, uibutton

I using `Helvetica Neue LT Std` font in my iOS app. When  i add a UIButton with `Helvetica Neue LT Std (67 Medium Condensed)`. It cut a bit in top of words. Like this:

[image]

You can see it loss a bit at "S" and "G".

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225761/custom-font-on-uibutton-title-clipped-on-top-of-word

Comment: Try giving top insets = 5

Answer (score 0):

Have a try `button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true`?