# Incorrect text on button

Tags: swift, button, text

When I set `button.setTitle("string")`
the letter **'g'** is missing a tail, like this:

[image]

Comment: have you set the button title programmatically or through IB ?

Comment: I set the title in swift file, not in story board :(

Comment: please paste the code you used to set the title

Comment: self.routeButton.setTitle(NSLocalizedString("search_route", comment: "ルート検索"), for: .normal)

Comment: routeButton is UIButton or your custom button?

Comment: @Hoan it was created in story board

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

Create a subclass of UIButton and override `layoutSubviews` func

```
class customButton: UIButton {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if var titleFrame : CGRect = titleLabel?.frame{
            titleFrame.size = self.bounds.size
            titleFrame.origin = .zero
            self.titleLabel!.frame = titleFrame
            self.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .center
        }
    }
}
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21279896/1441638).

Hope this helps.