# UIButton not resizing fontsize automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uibutton

I'm programmatically adding a UIButton to my view, and I want that font size into the button resize it automatically (e.g. if the text is long, resize to a smaller font to fit the button).

This code is not working (the font is always the same):

```
myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 180, 80)];
[myButton.titleLabel setFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0]];

myButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = TRUE;

[theView addSubview:myButton];
```

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178545/adjust-uibutton-font-size-to-width that did it for me

Comment: Also try calling the `sizeToFit` method on the button's titleLabel.

Comment: What behaviour do you want? Do you want the text to expand to fit the button, do you want the button to shrink to fit the text or do you want the text to shrink rather than be clipped if it to big to fit?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The code works, but perhaps not in the way you want it to. The `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property only ever reduces the font size if the text won't fit (down to the `minimumFontSize`). It will never increase the font size. In this case, a 16pt "hello" will easily fit in the 180pt wide button so no resizing will occur. If you want the font to increase to fit the space available you should increase it to a large number so that it will then be reduced to the maximum size that fits.

Just to show how it's currently working, here's a nice contrived example (click on the button to reduce its width as see the font reduce down to the `minimumFontSize`):

```c
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"hello"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [myButton setFrame: CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 120)];
    [myButton.titleLabel setFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:100.0]];
    myButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    myButton.titleLabel.minimumFontSize = 40;
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
}

- (void)buttonTap:(UIButton *)button {
    button.frame = CGRectInset(button.frame, 10, 0);
}
```

Comment: Ander, your code works like a charm, thank you very much!!! The only problem I still have is that, changing the content of the button (the text), it repositions itself upper or lower inside the button, instead of staying centered. It also seems that the starting position is infuenced also by the initial font size, even if it is adjusted later. I already tried to setContentVerticalAlignment:UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Code Works..!! I want to update :: Use 'minimumScaleFactor' instead 'minimumFontSize' as it is deprecated. So we can set minimum font size as -> myButton.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.4; (40 / 100).
Thanks..:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - was looking for a way to do this on UIButtons created in Storyboard, where it has settings for this for UILabel but not for UIButton. This is indeed works as expected - and yes, should use `minimumScaleFactor` instead.

Comment: You can set the values in a Storyboard if you select the UIButton and then view the identity inspector.  Under "User Defined Runtime Attributes"  enter the Key Path, Type, and Value you want to modify.  In this case: titleLabelFontSizeToFitWidth, Boolean, Yes;   titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor, Number, 0.2.  Works like a charm and no need to add code.