# Adjust font size of text to fit in UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uibutton, uilabel

I want to make sure the button text fits into a UIButton, while the UIButton has a fixed size.

Of course I can access the titleLabel of the UIButton.
In a label I would set `autoshrink` to minimum font scale which seems to correspond to

```
self.myButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

, but doesn't really behave the same, since it only makes the text fits horizontally into the bounds, not vertically, thereby not changing the font size.

How can i actually adjust the font size of a label programmatically to make the text fit into the label bounds (as shown in  **Goal**  in the picture below) ?

[image: adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth does not actually adjust the font size to fit the frame, only the width]

I already tried

```
self.myButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
self.myButton.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5f;
```

without success, always ended up as in `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` on the left side of the pic above.

**Edit**: *The solution also has to be ios7 compliant*

Comment: did you set  self.myButton.titleLabel.minimumFontSize property ?

Comment: I used minimumScaleFactor instead of minimumFontSize, but shouldn't make a difference functionality-wise I guess

Comment: oh and I just saw minimumFontSize is deprecated @Venkat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adjust UIButton font size to width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178545/adjust-uibutton-font-size-to-width)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
self.mybutton.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5f;
self.mybutton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;   <-- Or to desired number of lines
self.mybutton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

... did the trick, after layoutIfNeeded in viewDidLoad
As it turns out, all those must be set to actually adjust the font-size, not just making it fit into the frame.

#### Update for Swift 3:

```
mybutton.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
mybutton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0   <-- Or to desired number of lines
mybutton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: I had to set self.myButton.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1; otherwise there can be two lines.

Comment: @MarkHim I have the situation that the text fits horizontally in  button, but not vertically. In that situation it doesn't´t work ;-(  Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you have hard height constraints @mica i assume the intrinsic content size should be calculated correctly with my method, so just remove the height constraint and it should work fine

Comment: I had to add `self.mybutton.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByClipping` for this answer to work

Answer (score 11):

You can also set a User Defined Runtime Attribute in Interface Builder for the button where

```
titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: Indeed this is the correct answer. Be sure to not have Word Wrap (then it doesn't work) but to have Truncate Trailing or such. You can also have a number for titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor; but the titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth must be there. Hit the + sign on the User Defined Attributes in the Identity Inspector in Interface Builder while the Button is selected. Thanks @StackUnderflow.

Answer (score 11):

Updated code for Swift 3.0:

```
yourButton.titleLabel?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
yourButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
yourButton.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

Comment: Awesome solution :)

Answer (score 7):

to make text horizontally and vertically fit with button bounds :

1 - set button alignment like image (* VERY IMPORTANT *)

[image]

2 - add this lines of code in your ViewController

```
btnTest.setTitle("Test for multi line in button show line in button show Test for multi line in button show line in button show", for: .normal)
btnTest.titleLabel!.textAlignment = .center
btnTest.titleLabel!.numberOfLines = 0
btnTest.titleLabel!.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
btnTest.titleLabel!.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
// below line to add some inset for text to look better
// you can delete or change that
btnTest.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
```

- note that DON'T using `btnTest.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping` or other BreakMode in your code . for enable multiline in button . just using from above code

final result :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try to call the following method.

```
button.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustment.AlignCenters
```

Answer (score 2):

In Storyboard, Go to Link Break in Attributes Inspector, see word wrap..or set according to your choice.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
  [myButton setFont:[[myButton font] fontWithSize:--originalButtonFontSize]];
  textWidth = [text sizeWithFont:[myButton font]].width;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode->Open storyboard->Go to attributes inspector->Control->Alignment->Choose second in both horizontal and vertical.

or

```
YourButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

Answer (score -2):

If you prefer do in storyboard, just click the button, then show attributes inspector, and set the line break to "Word Wrap".

[image: word wrap]