# iOS Proportionally increase button height and width with font size according to device size by auto layout constraints

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have one view and one button. view is equal height and width to superview and button height and width will increase with font size according to device size by auto layout constraints

[image]

Comment: what is your question here?

Comment: You cannot do this solely with constraints and auto-layout. You need to set the font scaling properties on the `.titleLabel` of the button via code. Lots of answers, discussions and examples out there - for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32561435/adjust-font-size-of-text-to-fit-in-uibutton