# Change UIButton size according to string length

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, size

I have a bunch of string values that I want to be presented on buttons and so the button sizes need to change depending on the string. I thought I could do this using button.sizeToFit() but I get the following.

Is there a way to do something like sizeToFit() + some extra? I used padding but that caused the text to turn into "Healthcare...ness".

[image: Current button situation]

[image]

Code for the button:

```
class ExploreButton: UIButton {

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!

    }

    init() {
        super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
        self.titleLabel!.font = UIFont(name: "KohinoorBangla-Regular", size: 13)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.setTitleColor(UIColor(r: 30, g: 24, b: 25), forState: .Normal)
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 20
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor(r: 189, g: 195, b: 199).CGColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 2

        // self.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 5, 0, 5);

    }

}
```

Actual button setup:

```
let healthButton: ExploreButton = {
    let button = ExploreButton()
    button.setTitle("Healthcare, Spa & Fitness", forState: .Normal)
    button.sizeToFit()
    button.frame.size.width += 20
    return button
}()
```

Comment: A u t o l a y o u t

Comment: How are the buttons laid out? Are you giving the buttons a frame specifically or using autolayout? If you use autolayout and don't constrain the width, the buttons should size themselves automatically; with some default padding.

Comment: I'm not using autolayout since I'm trying to set it up programmatically

Comment: You could do `button.sizeToFit()` to allow it to lay itself out, then to add padding, you would do `button.frame.size.width += padding`.

Comment: @keithbhunter Should this work? I tried doing this and it changed nothing.

Comment: I can run this code in a playground and see that it will lay itself out and pad to the width, so yes it should work. Post your code that actually lays out the button.

Comment: @keithbhunter Edited to include it.

Comment: @keithbhunter help

Comment: I see you have subclassed `UIButton` to `ExploreButton`. Can I see the code for that? And I still don't see the code where you give the button x and y coordinates.

Comment: @keithbhunter I had them there before but I forgot to specify the class name! hope it is telling of something.

Comment: @keithbhunter interestingly when I use button.frame.size.width nothing seems to happen. Changing it using widthAnchor seems to work just fine though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Title edge inset properties of the button to add some padding on the left and right.

For example:

```
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 5.0)];
```

This can also be done via the story board by:

- Select the button
- Go to Edge Insets under Properties
- Select "Title"
- Change the Top, Left, Bottom and Right values as needed

Comment: That's what I used earlier and it works but it causes the writing to condense lol. I'll add another picture in the edit.

Comment: Does your button have a constraint for a fixed width? That is likely the issue

Comment: Not that I can see. I'm not using storyboard however. I've edited to include the button code.

Comment: Give this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6178995/2501735) a go. There's a swift version below it

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Your font size is staying the same, but the text is ellipsized.

Comment: yeah, the fontsize should remain constant. I tried just adding width after but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using constraints to add the button to a view, but if so, sometimes having a low compression resistance can result in the button contents being truncated.

Perhaps setting the compression resistance higher than default (750) will work better than sizeToFit:

```
button.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(UILayoutPriorityRequired, forAxis: .Horizontal)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it and the result seems to be the same as using sizeToFit for some reason.

Comment: Hmm... difficult to tell without more context. Does changing the line break mode from truncate middle to word wrap have any effect?

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't. Is there anything to keith's suggestion above?