# My button's titleLabel become "..." on iOS10

Tags: ios, uibutton, ios10

When I use iOS 10 some button label's text become "...".
I found the same string (e.x:我是人) in iOS9 uses 48 width. In iOS10 it uses 48.96 width. How to fix?

Comment: Make your button bigger.

Comment: Can u post screen shot of your button constraints?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" property of titleLabel of your button

Example:

```
  myButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

This line will automatically adjust font size for the text of myButton based on the width of the button.

Use this link: [adjust UIButton font size to width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178545/adjust-uibutton-font-size-to-width)

Another solution is to increase the width of the button, by adjusting constraints.

Comment: Thx,i fixed this.but i want to know why button in iOS10 is different from iOS9.

Comment: There might be some UI issues to be fixed when updating from one iOS version to a new one.