# Xcode Swift - iOS 10 & iOS 9 Text size problems

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios9, ios10

[image: This is what shows in the button on iOS 9 ONLY!]I've got a few buttons with text inside. If i run the app on an iOS 10 device, it works and shows the text fine. But running the app on iOS 9 the text inside the button is like "squashed" or "compressed"(the text on version 9 is missing the top and bottom part of the text). I'm not sure why this is happening, I've tried messing around with the hugging and compression settings on the UI Builder, but this hasn't really fixed the problem.

Not sure why it works on 10 but not on 9....The image above shows what the text looks like on iOS 9 ONLY!

I'm just seeing if this is happening with anyone else? or if anyone knows how to solve this problem?

I appreciate any help given! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this maybe help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39422382/my-buttons-titlelabel-become-on-ios10

Comment: What constraints do you have set on the button?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth" property of titleLabel of your button

Example:

```
  myButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

Comment: Hi! the width is fine you can still see the text, its just the top and bottom part of the text has been 'cut' off. so you can only see the the centre of the text, if thats understandable ?

Comment: @chriOSx but Scott need this answer on his question.

Comment: @Scott can you please try to change width and height once and then check it. thanks

Comment: @chriOsx its fine, i knew what you were pointing me too :) -> but this solution doesn't work :)

Comment: I've tried adjusting the heights and widths -> on my other buttons I have larger amount of texts, and they show fine... which is confusing me even more

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possibilities:

The height of the button during runtime could be wrong. Try setting a border to the button, run and observe the button outline to see if the height is correct.

```
myButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
myButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

If the height is wrong, it means the constraints could be incorrectly set up.

Another possibility might be `contentEdgeInsets`, `titleEdgeInsets` properties of the button having larger than intended top and bottom values.