# Font size in button change as screen size does

Tags: ios, iphone, button, text

In my IOS app there will be buttons with text on them. Everything looks fine only on Iphone 7, because it has screen size I've created on. When I switch to another screen size e.g. in simulator, text in buttons is truncated in the middle.

[image]

The best option to solve this problem would be to make font size scalable as screen size changes or slidable. How to make text in buttons visible at all in all screen sizes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178545/adjust-uibutton-font-size-to-width ? You should be able to set `minimumScaleFactor` too.

Comment: Could you type what the final code would look like? @Larme

Comment: How have you created the button? In storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: In storyboard, @RajeshkumarR

Comment: Have you created outlet for the button?