# How to resize UIButton's titleLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, label

My UIButton is dynamically resizable. And I want to use `adjustsFontSizeTofitWidth = true` to change titleLabel font dynamically, but problem is when I resize button, titleLabel doesn't resize. How to resize titleLabel?

```
backBtn.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)  //doesn't work

backBtn.titleLabel?.frame.size.width = backBtn.frame.size.width //doesn't work

backBtn.titleLabel?.clipsToBounds  = true //doesn't work

backBtn.titleLabel?.sizeThatFits(backBtn.frame.size)  //doesn't work
```

I have tried to look info here in google, but I didn't. Or just my questions are wrong.

Comment: Yes it's duplicate, but that link u provided doesn't solved problem

Comment: Did you even check the answers? The answer that you accepted is a exact copy of the last answer on that question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/27283248/7734643

Comment: sorry didn's see that. I checked answer marked as green

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**plaese use below code**

```
let label = self.button?.titleLabel
label?.minimumScaleFactor = 0.01
label?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
label?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(100)
```

Comment: Yes thank you!!!  label?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(100) this line is magic